# Tomcat 6 with servlet 3 spec

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Contrary to the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), is it possible to use Servlet specification 3 with Tomcat 6?

Comment: Will you be using features in the v3 spec but not the v2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the servlet 3 spec with tomcat 6?

I doubt this is a practical option.  You'd need to backport the Tomcat 7 servlet v3 stack to Tomcat 6.  In the process, there is a good chance you'd run into various Tomcat internal infrastructure issues that require significant work to address.

IMO, if you want to experiment with web applications that depend on the Servlet V3 specs on Tomcat your best bet is to try a [Tomcat 7 beta](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).  Alternatively, [Glassfish v3](http://glassfish.dev.java.net/) is now in production release and this implements the Servlet version 3.0 specification.

---

**UPDATE**

The first non-beta Tomcat 7.0 releases came out in [January 2011](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/).

Comment: That page is outdated. Servlet 3.0 and Java EE 6 are already final since 10 december 2009 and Glassfish 3 is already production ready for that long. http://glassfish.dev.java.net.