# How to make a Tomcat 7 app backwards compatible?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have developed a web application using **Tomcat 7** with **Servlet 3.0** specifications. What changes do I need to make it work on a server running Tomcat 6?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731609/tomcat-6-with-servlet-3-spec

Comment: Use **Servlet 2.5** !!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends what features you (or your framework) uses from the Servlet 3.0 specs. Figure that out, and you know the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are not using any features that are 3.0 specific,

What if you compile with `-target="1.6"` and run on Tomcat 6? You will need to have a web.xml, if you haven't already.

You may give it a shot, but I am not hopeful.